# Direct product vs categorical product

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, direct-product

Is what we call direct products (of groups, vector spaces, modules,...) actually the same as what we call categorical products? Why the word "direct"?

Comment: Yes they are. The word direct is as opposed to other forms of products that were given their name before category theory, e.g. the semi-direct product of groups

Answer (score -2):

no, direct sums are biproducts (coproducts and products). But what one usually writes as infinite "direct sum" is an infinite coproduct.

Comment: He didn't mention direct sums, rather direct products.

Comment: i know, but he most likely meant direct sums, regarding the categories he mentioned.

Comment: In the categories he mentioned, a finite direct product coincides with a finite direct sum. On the other hand, if I'm not mistaken, even with infinitely many objects, the categorical definition of a direct product is that of an infinite direct product of groups, vector spaces, modules,...

Comment: exactly! However, I am not sure how far he understood the differences between products and coproducts, and since he is asking for categories where one hardly uses the product interpretation, but more the coproduct one, I wanted to point that out!

Comment: Ah OK I see. You're right that direct sums are more used than direct products. Then maybe it'd be interesting to point out in your answer that the two notions are the same when taken over a finite family of elements, and that typically it's the direct sum that's used for infinite families.

Comment: There is no such thing as direct sum or biproduct of (non-abelian) groups.

Comment: @ArnaudD. I see. You're right. Thanks for pointing out that, I was mistaken as well. So when dealing with non abelian groups, the coproduct is rather the free product.

Comment: The notion exists non the less. Of course they do not exist always, however in abelian categories they do, and in a more general setting, although not guaranteed, those objects might still exist https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/biproduct
for example, in apointed category the zero object will always be the empty product and coproduct, hence it is the empty direct sum respectively biproduct.